# Traveling to the USA for 4 months and then South America for 6 months, will they still allow me into America if my return flight a year later?

Tags: visas, usa

I have just gotten my travel visa (B2) to USA for 10 years. I am going for my graduation and then traveling for four months. Afterwards I'll be traveling South America for five or six months.

Is there a certain amount of time that you are allowed to stay in the USA at one time and how do do I go about booking my return flights? Will they still allow me in the USA if my return flight is a year later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can arrive to the US as many times as you wish within the ten years but the actual entry grant will be given by the CBP officer.  After a few questions, the officer will stamp your passport with an amount of time (usually 6 months).  This determines how long you can stay in the US during this time.  Should you leave the US, that stamp duration is automatically ended and you can go anywhere for as long as you want and come back to the US and get stamped again.  Of course, as long as it is within the 10 year period of the visa.

Just remember that having the visa is not a guarantee of being allowed entry.  It hardly ever happens but technically a CBP officer can deny you entry.

More info here:

http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visitor.html#overview

and here:

http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/in-the-u-s-/entering.html

Comment: Thanks alot! And do you suggest that i book my flight for 6 months after i arrive and change it if i need to or is it ok if i book my flight a year later? Dont want to be denied entry if they think its suspicious that my flight is a year later.

Comment: The officers will not want to see your outbound flight information.  They are not interested in when you leave as long as you leave before the stamp expires.  It is your responsibility to comply with the time frame.